# How to show message author avatar adding a user id to the const

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i tried to use this code for an avatar command to use even outside servers' ids i can use .avatar @mention || .avatar id but .avatar to show up author's avatar doesn't work there's the error.

```
(node:9656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.User (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Constants.js:109:16)
    at RESTMethods.getUser (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RESTMethods.js:406:51)
    at Client.fetchUser (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:319:30)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\bot.js:963:31)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\zakaria\Desktop\test1011-master\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
(node:9656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9656) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

my code:

```
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command === 'avatar') {
        const userid = await client.fetchUser(args[0]);
        const User = message.mentions.users.first() || userid || message.author ;
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#000000')
            .setAuthor(`${User.username}#${User.discriminator}`, User.displayAvatarURL)
            .setDescription(`[Avatar Link](${User.avatarURL})`)
            .setImage(User.displayAvatarURL)
            .setFooter(`Requested By ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

Comment: You don't attempt to read a `property 'id'` anywhere in this code. Please provide the stack trace so we can see if it was an internal error.

Comment: i mean it works well when i use someones id but when i only do .avatar it doesn't work

Comment: The error you're getting didn't originate from your code. It either originated from discord.js internals (which we could diagnose with the stack trace) or code we don't have (which we could tell with the stack trace). Please edit the stack trace into your question

Comment: alright i edited the post and showed up the full trace message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error originates from [this line](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/v11/src/util/Constants.js#L109) in the discord.js source:

```
if (userID.id) userID = userID.id;
```

`userID` in this case is passed directly from `fetchUser(args[0])`. What this means is your `args[0]` was undefined, but you tried to `client.fetchUser(undefined)` anyway, and discord.js threw a mysterious error because it didn't check the user input in `fetchUser()`.

To fix you merely need to use a conditional such that you don't try to make invalid requests. I suggest something like this:

```
if(command === 'avatar') {
    const User = message.mentions.users.first() ||
                 (args[0] && await client.fetchUser(args[0])) ||
                 message.author;
    const embed = ...
}
```